# hg revision specifier for Nth entry in the obslog? (evolve extension)

Tags: mercurial

I'm using Mercurial with the [evolve extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/EvolveExtension).  Is there a revision specifier that means "the Nth first parent in the obslog for revision X"?

After I rebase a commit I would like to be able to quickly get the diff between the pre-rebased version of the commit and the post-rebased version.  (Something similar to Git's `@{1}` revision specifier.)

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for the journal extension? https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/JournalExtension

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reference the first parent in obslog (called `precursor`) by using the following revset: `hg log -r "precursors(.)" --hidden`. The problem is that you can have multiple precursors for a single revision.

If you are sure you have a linear obsolescence history, you can access the Nth parent by calling precursors several times: `hg log -r "precursors(precursors(.))"`.

Comment: PS: I'm the author of the obslog command, please feel free to send me any feedback you have on obslog and/or Evolve.

Comment: Is there any reason this isn't documented in https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/help/revsets ?

Comment: Those revsets are defined in the evolve extension, you can find their implementation and documentation here: https://foss.heptapod.net/mercurial/evolve/-/blob/branch/default/hgext3rd/evolve/__init__.py#L575

Comment: In addition, they are documented in `hg help revsets` so it should returns the correct documentation based on your Mercurial and evolve version